# Pass object through ui-router to controller

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm creating a user profile page using angular/rails. I've set up a StateProvider using ui-router, like so,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('friendprofile', {
    url: '/{name}',
    views: {
      "friendProfile": {
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_friendProfile.html',
        controller: 'friendProfileCtrl',
      }
    },
  })
```

This is the click action from the template,

```
%a.profile{"ui-sref" => "friendprofile(user)"}
  name: {{ user.name }}
```

Note that I'm passing `user` here.

So when the link `.profile` is clicked I go to the url http://localhost:3000/#/Jan%20Jansen. So that's working fine.

In my `friendProfileCtrl` I have a function that calls a service,

```
friendProfileService.loadProfile().then(function(response) {
  $scope.user_profile = response.data;
  console.log ($scope.user_profile)
})
```

Which calls this service,

```
app.factory('friendProfileService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    loadProfile: function() {
      return $http.get('/users/4.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

Currently I have the return url `users/4/.json` hardcoded. Can I get the users id in there somehow? Or do I have to resolve it in the StateProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `id` parameter of user inside state so that it can be easily readable from the `$stateParams`.

```
url: '/{id}/{name}', //assuming user object has `id` property which has unique id.
```

So while making an ajax you could directly get the user `id` from the user object before making an ajax.

**Controller**

```
friendProfileService.loadProfile($stateParams.id).then(function(response) {
  $scope.user_profile = response.data;
  console.log ($scope.user_profile)
})
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('friendProfileService', ['$http', '$stateParams', function($http) {
  return {
    loadProfile: function(id) {
      return $http.get('/users/'+ id +'json');
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could pass `$stateParams` through. Looks like it's working.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Great.. Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You've said right - you should resolve it before controller loads:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('friendprofile', {
    url: '/{name}',
    views: {
      "friendProfile": {
        templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_friendProfile.html',
        controller: 'friendProfileCtrl',
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      user: function($stateParams, friendProfileService) {
        friendProfileService.loadProfile($stateParams.name);
      }
    }
  })
```

And then in the controller you can inject `user` variable which won't be a promise but the resolved data already:

```
app.controller('friendProfileCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'user',
  ...
  function($scope, user, ...) {
    $scope.user_profile = user;
    console.log($scope.user_profile)
  }
]);
```

Btw the value for `ui-sref` should be something like that: `friendprofile({name: user})`

And don't forget to add input parameter to `loadProfile` function. Probably you should better rename `{name}` parameter to `{id}`